# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 18.04, Qualcomm Atheros Device abcd (rev 01)

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, atheros

I'm having trouble getting my wifi to work. It works fine in Windows though.

`lspci` displays `Qualcomm Atheros Device abcd (rev 01)`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Qualcomm Atheros
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fd500000-fd51ffff memory:fd520000-fd52ffff
```

Machine uses ATHK9 according to the manufacture's website

http://febsmart.com/download.php.
(FS-N600-Basic Edition)

How can I fix/debug this?